# Usage of modal verb Could

Tags: modal-verbs, could-modal

> How **could** we spend this time on the island?

Does this mean 1)It is impossible or difficult for us to spend time in the island?   Or   2) What are the possible means to stay in the forest?

If the given sentence doesn’t mean the above two cases, what does it mean?

Comment: It does basically mean both those things.

Comment: So which option strikes to their heads for native speakers, when they first hear of the given sentence?

Answer (score 1):

How could we spend this time on the island?

1. By what means (hotel, money. a tent etc.)
2. What to do while there, the activities, in the sense of how to spend one's time.
3. There is also a **use of could** that goes to surprise about a person's actions.

**How could  you do this to me?** [It expresses outrage or anger]

How could we spend this time on the island [when our grandparents have just died.]